# Has anyone tried to cook spaghetti or other pasta in a skillet?

Tags: pasta

I was watching Sara Moulton's TV show last night. She did a segment on breakfast for dinner. Part of the one recipe involves browning the pasta in a skillet first. Later on, it is cooked with some chicken stock and water.

http://saramoulton.com/2016/01/spaghetti-with-bacon-eggs-and-toasted-crumbs/

Has anyone tried cooking this way? Does the pasta take on a different flavor or texture?

Comment: Are you asking about the *browning* or the use of a *skillet and comparatively little water*?

Comment: https://food52.com/blog/16313-roast-pasta-before-cooking-it-really others are researching that technique too :) And I am sure I have seen fire-roasted pasta sold at high prices in stores.

Comment: Stephie: Both. I could see from the recipe demonstrated on the TV program that the pasta was changed by the browning. And, there was some moisture in the skillet from the previously cooked items. I would think the remains of the butter and onions that were previously cooked would add something to the pasta even though it would be dry. I was hoping for some insights from some more experienced cooks/chefs here.

Answer (score 4):

It adds a little bit of "nutiness"; it is subtle and depends on the other flavors in the dish.

It is the same thing when sauteing rice (or other grains) in oil or butter before adding water.

I've done it a few times, but long time ago.